# Null column for username and password when using Login with *social network*

Tags: database-design

I want to know what are the conventions for columns like `username` and `password` when your application supports login with a third party, like **login with facebook** for instance.

Given the fact that when you Log with a 3rd party, you don't really need to specify a `username`, you'll just specify the 3rd party `user id`, in database design, you can expect either a `blank` field or a `null` value.

Since usernames are `UNIQUE`, I'm guessing going for `nullable` is the way to go, since it allows multiple null columns.

The real issue is that the user needs to specify **either** a username **OR** a 3rd party id. Which means **both columns can be null, but not at the same time**

So what's the convention for handling this design pattern?

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather separate user and authentication mechanism/provider. Application may allow more than one authentication provider (say , logins with facebook, openid, etc). Adding columns/constraints every time you add a new authentication option doesn't sound like a very good idea to me (even though that doesn't happen often, such an action usually requires lots of changes on application side).
Something like

```
user(user_id);
authenticator (authenticator_id, name, description, authentication_type);
user_authentication(user_id, authenticator_id, authentication_identity, authenticator_token) ;
```

seems more general to me.

** In case of username/password authentication you can keep username in `authentication_identity` and password (surely not plain text) in `authenticator_token`. If you feel the pair `authentication_identity/authenticator_token` doesn't cover all the cases you can add couple more tables that store information specific to particular `authentication_type`

Comment: email password login would require the password to be hashed but social login would give you an access token, a refresh token and an expires column telling when the tokens expire, how will this get stored n your authenticator table, also what happens if the social login user decides to set a password

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur how you store username and password in your database.
Do you store the data in your own tables or do you rely on the login and password that you need to connect to SQL Server?

Assuming it's the former then your assumption of a username being unique is only valid if there's a single 3rd party app (like facebook). But as soon as there are several 3rd party apps (e.g. facebook and twitter) you'll need to identify the username and the app it belongs to.
Regarding the two columns being nullable:
You could use a CHECK constraint to enforce data integrity (assuming both columns having the same data type...):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].YourTable  ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_YourTable] CHECK  ((ISNULL(username,3rdpartyid) IS NOT NULL))
```