# How can I handle multiple social logins per user and yet unique email in this database schema?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I am trying to create a postgres database for a webapp that has users that either login with email/password combo or with social accounts. I would like to do it such that once logged in a person is also able to link other social accounts.

[Based on a similar question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74459/null-column-for-username-and-password-when-using-login-with-social-network), I came across this database schema storing 3 tables to solve the above issue

```
user(user_id);
authenticator (authenticator_id, name, description, authentication_type);
user_authentication(user_id, authenticator_id, authentication_identity, authenticator_token) ;
```

I tried populating some fields in the above 3 tables

```
+-------+
| users |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
+-------+


+------------------+----------+--------------------+---------------------+
| authenticator_id |   name   |    description     | authentication_type |
+------------------+----------+--------------------+---------------------+
|                1 | password | login via password | password            |
|                2 | facebook | login via facebook | facebook            |
|                3 | google   | login via google   | google              |
|                4 | twitter  | login via twitter  | twitter             |
+------------------+----------+--------------------+---------------------+


+---------+-------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_id | authentication_id | authentication_identity |                     authentication_token                     |
+---------+-------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1 |                 1 | abc@gmail.com           | $2b$11$xwyYcDOlRBRQNQYdzmTYVuqRSxswsSzxINJdKl0bWuHFzCWZYztpy |
|       2 |                 1 | bcd@gmail.com           | $2b$11$xwyYcDOlRBRQNQYdzmTYVuqRSxswsSzxINJdKl0bWuHFzCWZYztpy |
|       2 |                 2 | bcd@gmail.com           |                                                              |
|       3 |                 1 | cde@gmail.com           | $2b$11$xwyYcDOlRBRQNQYdzmTYVuqRSxswsSzxINJdKl0bWuHFzCWZYztpy |
|       3 |                 3 | def@gmail.com           |                                                              |
+---------+-------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have 2 problems in this schema

1. bcd@gmail.com is repeating twice. The email has to be unique
2. If we take the email and pair it with users to make it unique, it creates a second problem. Let's say you make an account with abc@gmail.com and a password. 1 month later you come and login with Facebook (which has the same email abc@gmail.com) It wont accept this Facebook login because it will try to create an entry for abc@gmail.com which already exists.

How can I keep the email unique but at the same time let a user link multiple social accounts?

Comment: Is a email/pw required or can someone use social accounts without providing that information?

Comment: @bbaird a person who registers on the website using an email password combination is required to enter them everytime but if they use a social login to signup on the website then no

Comment: And when they choose a social login to signup, what are the values stored as part of that process?

Comment: for an email password based login, it stores email password, nickname and for a social login it stores social_login_user_id (a special user id allocated by the social login provider) email and nickname

Comment: I don't have time to type a full answer at the moment but look at this fiddle and see if it makes sense: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1b7bb92d766f3e6ce989d2fa9b3f419b

Comment: @bbaird thank you very much for putting a fiddle, there is only 1 issue i can see in this. In the fiddle above, the user id needs to be created first. Lets say the structure of the table was different where social login id, email was the primary key and did not require creating a user_id first. The first time user creates an account or signs in, you will be able to insert a row into this table and on successful insert create a new user id. the second time you insert the same value you will get a violates duplicate constraint error and you can avoid creating a new user id

Comment: That sounds like something that should be handled in transactional logic (add user if email doesn't exist/etc).  `UserId` here is essentially meaningless - it's a pointer we use to tie disparate things together.  We shouldn't have to assign it more than once.

Comment: @bbaird thank you very much! that seems rock solid! i would be super happy to upvote this if you ever find time to post! you sir, rule!